How to extract predictions, say of survival probability, of the outer loop sample during nested cv (mlr3 benchmark)?

Note: The code/analysis output of this question has been edited using reprex() upon request to increase reproducibility

I would appreciate some guidance on extraction of distributional predictions (eg event probability at a particular time point), linear predictors from the outer loop of a nested cv, and extraction of the baseline hazard from the inner loop of a nested cv (where the model is developed) during mlr3 benchmarking procedures to calculate calibration indexes.
Using the lung dataset as an example:
rm(list = (ls(all=T)))
library(reprex)
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3tuning)
#> Loading required package: paradox
library(mlr3proba)
library(data.table)

# set up data
task_lung = tsk('lung')
d = task_lung$data()
d$time = ceiling(d$time/30.44)
task_lung = as_task_surv(d, time = 'time', event = 'status', id = 'lung')
po_encode = po('encode', method = 'treatment')
po_impute = po('imputelearner', lrn('regr.rpart'))
pre = po_encode %>>% po_impute
task = pre$train(task_lung)[[1]]


# learners
cph=lrn("surv.coxph")
# get baseline hazard estimates
comp.cph = as_learner(ppl(  
  "distrcompositor",
  learner = cph,
  estimator = "kaplan",
  form = "ph"
))



# Benchmark above 3 (in outer 4 folds)
set.seed(123)
BM1 = benchmark(benchmark_grid(task,
                      list(cph, comp.cph),
                      rsmp('cv', folds=4)),
                store_models =T)
#> INFO  [13:00:22.564] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 8 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [13:00:22.649] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 1/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:22.716] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 2/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:22.766] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 3/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:22.825] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 4/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:22.873] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.surv.coxph.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 1/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:23.029] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.surv.coxph.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 2/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:23.225] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.surv.coxph.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 3/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:23.365] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.surv.coxph.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 4/4)
#> INFO  [13:00:23.510] [mlr3] Finished benchmark

# extract (inner) models
mdl=mlr3misc::map(as.data.table(BM1)$learner, "model")

# check that the LP is for internal loop
# the following has 171 obs as expected from inner loops
mdl[[1]][["linear.predictors"]]
#>   [1]  1.18499215  0.31858695  0.99802300  0.58241827  0.15774088 -0.12313273
#>   [7]  0.27176230  0.31255547  0.87977282  1.66127703  1.27052489  0.32452650
#>  [13] -0.39147459  0.18128928  0.40221932  0.32179235  1.29488433  0.22421192
#>  [19]  0.36696516  0.02351139  0.03435003  0.30268183  0.46156831  0.67854111
#>  [25] -0.38466200  0.18029125 -0.30794694  1.81985726  0.72143148  0.73993999
#>  [31] -0.19820495 -0.61578221  1.41832763  0.61361444  0.26284730  1.59711534
#>  [37]  0.08964261 -0.39070785  0.34200863  0.63126957  1.02630566  0.01239987
#>  [43]  0.23198859 -0.26151613 -0.39089134  0.19280407 -0.87206586 -0.62197655
#>  [49]  0.88013192  0.08972523 -0.74319591 -1.03042024 -0.27852335  0.08151983
#>  [55]  1.71881259 -0.67763599  1.11294971  0.88264769  0.10990293 -0.02842130
#>  [61]  0.37947992  0.49182045  0.77795647  0.71053557  0.65215179  0.27799555
#>  [67] -0.37213111  1.88280007  1.19325541 -0.12267881  1.15952023 -0.94928614
#>  [73]  0.86114411  0.31579099  1.91908641  0.77277223 -0.04938800  0.39655017
#>  [79] -0.02114651  1.77783288  1.01903263  0.67158262  0.49602602 -0.53871485
#>  [85]  1.13274466  0.24812544  1.61907952 -0.01141713  0.85803147  0.94607458
#>  [91] -0.41149162  0.35978972  1.53106530  1.31347748  0.12968634  0.95718654
#>  [97]  1.21293718  0.90307591 -0.10667084  0.87119681  0.94642450 -0.40357218
#> [103]  0.21266674  0.54770469  0.60351288  0.61024865 -1.15985267 -0.60745992
#> [109]  0.64926122  0.94255144  0.10625227 -0.17035191  0.35624501  0.78856855
#> [115]  0.82062314  0.64819105  0.29187039  0.83125774  1.40013302  0.64771200
#> [121]  1.15793176  0.62013293  0.13332034  0.11379916  0.53277392  0.67303587
#> [127]  0.07299108 -0.22845207 -0.37492090 -0.22763493  0.18024949 -0.45301382
#> [133] -0.11000587  0.10124783  0.11111948  0.43462859  1.19243908  0.87027351
#> [139]  1.32904450  0.14259790  0.39245370  0.62142923 -0.33833996  0.48248721
#> [145]  0.94495937  1.09431650  0.78709427  0.18538695 -0.26797215 -0.40705985
#> [151]  1.49430202  1.47283382 -1.12637695 -0.16080892 -0.35788332  0.57572753
#> [157] -0.85507993 -0.05270265 -0.11091513  0.60276879 -0.35633053  0.47495284
#> [163]  0.81178544  0.73027874 -0.43725719 -0.22938202 -0.28038346  0.54849467
#> [169]  0.06449779  1.38581779 -0.29679293

# extract baseline hazard 
# Assuming that these are from inner loops (which is required for distributional prediction)
mdl[[5]][["distrcompositor.kaplan"]][["model"]][["std.chaz"]]
#>  [1] 0.01547223 0.02062259 0.02649866 0.03237961 0.03735763 0.04532140
#>  [7] 0.05320536 0.05999788 0.06527124 0.07576031 0.08515480 0.10010706
#> [13] 0.10877590 0.11161182 0.12888880 0.13672413 0.13672413 0.14575496
#> [19] 0.15721555 0.16497494 0.17407800 0.19293410 0.20412743 0.23869255
#> [25] 0.27111447 0.32365577 0.36404785 0.36404785 0.49360100 0.49360100


# Extract outer learners based on a previous question: "mlr3, benchmarking and nested resampling: how to extract a tuned model from a benchmark object to calculate feature importance, the suggested code to extract learners fitted in the outer loop" @ https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/601

data = as.data.table(BM1)
outer_learners = mlr3misc::map(data$learner, "learner"); outer_learners  #outer_learners is null
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> NULL


# Based on the following https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/601, it may be possible to save the best model from inner cv and apply this model for prediction on a new/outer dataset (This is not working too)
measures = list (
  msr('surv.cindex', id='cindex'),
  msr('surv.graf', id='brier'))
best_mdl <- BM1$score(measures)[learner_id=='encode.scale.surv.glmnet.tuned',][cindex==max(cindex)]$learners
#> Warning in max(cindex): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Created on 2024-05-03 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 10.16         
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Australia/Adelaide          
#>  date     2024-05-03                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package           * version     date       lib
#>  backports           1.4.1       2021-12-13 [1]
#>  bbotk               0.7.3.9000  2023-11-22 [1]
#>  checkmate           2.3.1       2023-12-04 [1]
#>  cli                 3.6.2       2023-12-11 [1]
#>  codetools           0.2-18      2020-11-04 [2]
#>  colorspace          2.1-0       2023-01-23 [1]
#>  crayon              1.4.1       2021-02-08 [2]
#>  data.table        * 1.15.4      2024-03-30 [1]
#>  dictionar6          0.1.3       2021-09-13 [1]
#>  digest              0.6.35      2024-03-11 [1]
#>  distr6              1.8.4       2024-05-02 [1]
#>  dplyr               1.1.3       2023-09-03 [1]
#>  evaluate            0.23        2023-11-01 [1]
#>  fansi               1.0.6       2023-12-08 [1]
#>  fastmap             1.1.0       2021-01-25 [2]
#>  fs                  1.5.0       2020-07-31 [2]
#>  future              1.33.2      2024-03-26 [1]
#>  future.apply        1.11.2      2024-03-28 [1]
#>  generics            0.1.3       2022-07-05 [1]
#>  ggplot2             3.5.1       2024-04-23 [1]
#>  globals             0.16.3      2024-03-08 [1]
#>  glue                1.7.0       2024-01-09 [1]
#>  gtable              0.3.5       2024-04-22 [1]
#>  highr               0.9         2021-04-16 [2]
#>  htmltools           0.5.6       2023-08-10 [1]
#>  knitr               1.33        2021-04-24 [2]
#>  lattice             0.20-44     2021-05-02 [2]
#>  lgr                 0.4.4       2022-09-05 [1]
#>  lifecycle           1.0.4       2023-11-07 [1]
#>  listenv             0.9.1       2024-01-29 [1]
#>  magrittr            2.0.3       2022-03-30 [1]
#>  Matrix              1.3-4       2021-06-01 [2]
#>  mlr3              * 0.19.0      2024-04-24 [1]
#>  mlr3extralearners * 0.7.1       2023-11-24 [1]
#>  mlr3learners      * 0.5.7.9000  2023-11-24 [1]
#>  mlr3misc            0.15.0      2024-04-10 [1]
#>  mlr3pipelines     * 0.5.0-9000  2023-11-22 [1]
#>  mlr3proba         * 0.6.1       2024-05-02 [1]
#>  mlr3tuning        * 0.19.1.9000 2023-11-22 [1]
#>  mlr3viz             0.8.0       2024-03-05 [1]
#>  munsell             0.5.1       2024-04-01 [1]
#>  ooplah              0.2.0       2022-01-21 [1]
#>  palmerpenguins      0.1.1       2022-08-15 [1]
#>  paradox           * 0.11.1-9000 2023-11-22 [1]
#>  parallelly          1.37.1      2024-02-29 [1]
#>  param6              0.2.4       2023-11-22 [1]
#>  pillar              1.9.0       2023-03-22 [1]
#>  pkgconfig           2.0.3       2019-09-22 [2]
#>  R6                  2.5.1       2021-08-19 [1]
#>  Rcpp                1.0.12      2024-01-09 [1]
#>  reprex            * 2.0.1       2021-08-05 [1]
#>  RhpcBLASctl         0.23-42     2023-02-11 [1]
#>  rlang               1.1.3       2024-01-10 [1]
#>  rmarkdown           2.10        2021-08-06 [2]
#>  rpart               4.1-15      2019-04-12 [2]
#>  rstudioapi          0.15.0      2023-07-07 [1]
#>  scales              1.3.0       2023-11-28 [1]
#>  sessioninfo         1.1.1       2018-11-05 [2]
#>  set6                0.2.6       2023-11-22 [1]
#>  stringi             1.7.3       2021-07-16 [2]
#>  stringr             1.5.0       2022-12-02 [1]
#>  survival            3.5-7       2023-08-14 [1]
#>  survivalmodels      0.1.191     2024-03-19 [1]
#>  tibble              3.2.1       2023-03-20 [1]
#>  tidyselect          1.2.0       2022-10-10 [1]
#>  utf8                1.2.4       2023-10-22 [1]
#>  uuid                1.2-0       2024-01-14 [1]
#>  vctrs               0.6.5       2023-12-01 [1]
#>  withr               3.0.0       2024-01-16 [1]
#>  xfun                0.25        2021-08-06 [2]
#>  yaml                2.2.1       2020-02-01 [2]
#>  source                                    
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  https://mlr-org.r-universe.dev (R 4.1.1)  
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  Github (xoopR/distr6@a7c01f7)             
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  Github (mlr-org/mlr3extralearners@6e2af9e)
#>  Github (mlr-org/mlr3learners@86f19eb)     
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  https://mlr-org.r-universe.dev (R 4.1.1)  
#>  https://mlr-org.r-universe.dev (R 4.1.1)  
#>  https://mlr-org.r-universe.dev (R 4.1.1)  
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  https://mlr-org.r-universe.dev (R 4.1.1)  
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  Github (xoopR/param6@0fa3577)             
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  Github (xoopR/set6@a901255)               
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#> 
#> [1] /Users/Lee/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library
#> [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library

I would very much appreciate any advice/suggestions on how to extract the relevant results on the inner loop and apply these results for prediction tasks on the outer loop samples during nested-cv benchmarking procedures in mlr3.

Short answer
... to the original title: you already have the predictions of the outer-loop, it's in the data$prediction slot.
Details on the code/Suggestions
learners
cph=lrn("surv.coxph")
# get baseline hazard estimates

Notes:

with distrcompositor you compose S(t) (survival prediction), you are not getting the baseline S_0(t). Using a CoxPH model, you don't need to compose an S(t), the one used by the survival package by default (Breslow) is good enough. I think later you need just the trained Kaplan fit (survfit), so you could just use lrn("surv.kaplan").
argument overwrite is FALSE by default so you are not adding anything by using the distrcompositor here. Just making your life more difficult to get the learner that's inside the PipeOp afterwards (if you need that).

comp.cph = as_learner(ppl(  
  "distrcompositor",
  learner = cph,
  estimator = "kaplan",
  form = "ph"
))
comp.cph # see that `distrcompose.overwrite=FALSE`, so SAME S(t) as `cph` learner


read ?mlr_learners_surv.glmnet, s tuning is not supported, tune the lambda parameter, see example code here => https://github.com/bblodfon/mlr3tests/blob/main/mlr3proba/coxnet/add_distr.R#L97

lasso = as_learner(
  po("encode") %>>% 
  po('scale') %>>% # standardize = TRUE by default in glmnet so this is re-done
    # Note: good to write the arguments, eg `tuner = ...`
  auto_tuner(
    tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 10, batch_size =10),
    learner = lrn("surv.glmnet", alpha=1, s = to_tune(0.005, 1)),
    resampling = rsmp("cv", folds=2),
    measure = msr(c("surv.cindex")),
    store_models = TRUE,
    terminator = trm("stagnation", iters=50, threshold=0.01))
  )


I assume the baseline hazards extracted above were also based on the inner sample (which is required for outer sample (distributional) prediction for cph/lasso)

YES, since:
mdl[[9]]$distrcompositor.kaplan$model$n (171 = #samples in 3 out of 4 folds)


the suggested code to extract learners fitted in the outer loop is not working:

It was a different example there, I get a different error when running it:
data = as.data.table(BM1)
outer_learners = mlr3misc::map(data$learner, "learner")
Error in `[[.R6`(X[[i]], ...) :
R6 class LearnerSurvCoxPH/LearnerSurv/Learner/R6 does not have slot 'learner'!

But look, data$learner is the list of learners you are asking for, i.e. the 'tuned'/'trained' version of learners (on the 3 out of 4 folds), ready to be used for making predictions.

...it may be possible to save the best model from inner cv (is the
data$learner) and apply this model for prediction on a new/outer dataset:

measures = list(msr('surv.cindex', id='cindex'), msr('surv.graf', id='brier'))
BM1$score(measures) # this works for me, no problem, update packages will fix this


I would very much appreciate any hints/suggestions on how to extract the relevant results on the inner loop and apply these results for prediction tasks on the outer loop samples from nested-cv benchmarking procedures in mlr3.

The outer-loop sample predictions are exactly the following (#samples = 57 = 228/4, ie 1 outer-fold):
data$prediction
...

[[12]]
<PredictionSurv> for 57 observations:
    row_ids time status       crank          lp     distr
         18   24   TRUE  0.82866010  0.82866010 <list[1]>
         21   10   TRUE  0.72062419  0.72062419 <list[1]>
         26   18   TRUE  0.33464409  0.33464409 <list[1]>
---                                                      
        222    7  FALSE  0.07149053  0.07149053 <list[1]>
        224    7  FALSE  1.65191498  1.65191498 <list[1]>
        228    6  FALSE -0.40258256 -0.40258256 <list[1]>


Please update ALL mlr3-related packages to the latest CRAN or github version, primarily mlr3proba, mlr3extralearners, mlr3pipelines and paradox, since your versions are a bit old and there might be some differences. Note all these packages have recently had some core updates to make things better and faster, etc. so good to do in general.


Thank you very much @John for such a detailed explanation!
I have updated all my mlr3 packages. The event probability at 12 months can be extracted by the following:
rm(list = (ls(all=T)))
library(reprex)
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3tuning)
#> Loading required package: paradox
library(mlr3proba)
library(data.table)

# set up data
task_lung = tsk('lung')
d = task_lung$data()
d$time = ceiling(d$time/30.44)
task_lung = as_task_surv(d, time = 'time', event = 'status', id = 'lung')
po_encode = po('encode', method = 'treatment')
po_impute = po('imputelearner', lrn('regr.rpart'))
pre = po_encode %>>% po_impute
task = pre$train(task_lung)[[1]]

## update ----
# learners
cph=lrn("surv.coxph")
lasso_cv=as_learner(po("encode") %>>% lrn("surv.cv_glmnet", alpha=1))

# get baseline hazard estimates
comp.lasso = as_learner(ppl(  
  "distrcompositor",
  learner = lasso_cv,
  estimator = "kaplan",
  form = "ph",
  overwrite=T
))

# Benchmark 
set.seed(123)
BM1 = benchmark(benchmark_grid(task,
                               list(cph, comp.lasso),
                               rsmp('cv', folds=4)),
                store_models =T)
#> INFO  [14:01:37.465] [mlr3] Running benchmark with 8 resampling iterations
#> INFO  [14:01:37.543] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 1/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:37.617] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 2/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:37.667] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 3/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:37.718] [mlr3] Applying learner 'surv.coxph' on task 'lung' (iter 4/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:37.780] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.encode.surv.cv_glmnet.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 1/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:38.182] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.encode.surv.cv_glmnet.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 2/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:38.468] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.encode.surv.cv_glmnet.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 3/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:38.760] [mlr3] Applying learner 'distrcompositor.kaplan.encode.surv.cv_glmnet.distrcompose' on task 'lung' (iter 4/4)
#> INFO  [14:01:39.050] [mlr3] Finished benchmark

# extract predictions
data = as.data.table(BM1)
prediction=data$prediction[[1]]$distr$cdf(12); prediction
#>         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     [,7]
#> 12 0.8686652 0.6513526 0.6632674 0.5627742 0.6789522 0.7448857 0.986712
#>         [,8]      [,9]     [,10]     [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]
#> 12 0.5392825 0.7935518 0.3706395 0.7059414 0.8081155 0.5089938 0.3910548
#>        [,15]     [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]     [,20]     [,21]
#> 12 0.5672167 0.7728258 0.3917137 0.8721809 0.9036236 0.6969692 0.5653464
#>        [,22]     [,23]     [,24]     [,25]     [,26]     [,27]     [,28]
#> 12 0.5702154 0.6233811 0.5467938 0.7065965 0.7522205 0.6615671 0.6955122
#>        [,29]    [,30]     [,31]     [,32]     [,33]     [,34]     [,35]
#> 12 0.3209718 0.354291 0.8935842 0.5169422 0.6813937 0.5295419 0.4575189
#>        [,36]     [,37]    [,38]     [,39]   [,40]     [,41]    [,42]     [,43]
#> 12 0.4929804 0.3104184 0.311706 0.5188105 0.41493 0.8426954 0.758004 0.2428518
#>        [,44]     [,45]     [,46]     [,47]     [,48]     [,49]     [,50]
#> 12 0.3282441 0.7899832 0.9024987 0.4497594 0.1970961 0.8355801 0.7091504
#>        [,51]    [,52]     [,53]     [,54]     [,55]     [,56]     [,57]
#> 12 0.3663186 0.728922 0.6827471 0.7519496 0.8476087 0.9295624 0.6314854
prediction.lasso=data$prediction[[5]]$distr$cdf(12) ; prediction.lasso
#>         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>         [,8]      [,9]     [,10]     [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>        [,15]     [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]     [,20]     [,21]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>        [,22]     [,23]     [,24]     [,25]     [,26]     [,27]     [,28]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>        [,29]     [,30]     [,31]     [,32]     [,33]     [,34]     [,35]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>        [,36]     [,37]     [,38]     [,39]     [,40]     [,41]     [,42]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>        [,43]     [,44]     [,45]     [,46]     [,47]     [,48]     [,49]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>        [,50]     [,51]     [,52]     [,53]     [,54]     [,55]     [,56]
#> 12 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414 0.6124414
#>        [,57]
#> 12 0.6124414

Created on 2024-05-04 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 10.16         
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Australia/Adelaide          
#>  date     2024-05-04                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package           * version     date       lib
#>  backports           1.4.1       2021-12-13 [1]
#>  bbotk               0.8.0       2024-02-29 [1]
#>  checkmate           2.3.1       2023-12-04 [1]
#>  cli                 3.6.2       2023-12-11 [1]
#>  codetools           0.2-18      2020-11-04 [2]
#>  colorspace          2.1-0       2023-01-23 [1]
#>  crayon              1.4.1       2021-02-08 [2]
#>  data.table        * 1.15.4      2024-03-30 [1]
#>  dictionar6          0.1.3       2021-09-13 [1]
#>  digest              0.6.35      2024-03-11 [1]
#>  distr6              1.8.4       2024-05-02 [1]
#>  dplyr               1.1.3       2023-09-03 [1]
#>  evaluate            0.23        2023-11-01 [1]
#>  fansi               1.0.6       2023-12-08 [1]
#>  fastmap             1.1.0       2021-01-25 [2]
#>  foreach             1.5.1       2020-10-15 [2]
#>  fs                  1.5.0       2020-07-31 [2]
#>  future              1.33.2      2024-03-26 [1]
#>  future.apply        1.11.2      2024-03-28 [1]
#>  generics            0.1.3       2022-07-05 [1]
#>  ggplot2             3.5.1       2024-04-23 [1]
#>  glmnet              4.1-2       2021-06-24 [2]
#>  globals             0.16.3      2024-03-08 [1]
#>  glue                1.7.0       2024-01-09 [1]
#>  gtable              0.3.5       2024-04-22 [1]
#>  highr               0.9         2021-04-16 [2]
#>  htmltools           0.5.6       2023-08-10 [1]
#>  iterators           1.0.13      2020-10-15 [2]
#>  knitr               1.33        2021-04-24 [2]
#>  lattice             0.20-44     2021-05-02 [2]
#>  lgr                 0.4.4       2022-09-05 [1]
#>  lifecycle           1.0.4       2023-11-07 [1]
#>  listenv             0.9.1       2024-01-29 [1]
#>  magrittr            2.0.3       2022-03-30 [1]
#>  Matrix              1.3-4       2021-06-01 [2]
#>  mlr3              * 0.19.0      2024-04-24 [1]
#>  mlr3extralearners * 0.7.1       2023-11-24 [1]
#>  mlr3learners      * 0.6.0       2024-03-13 [1]
#>  mlr3misc            0.15.0      2024-04-10 [1]
#>  mlr3pipelines     * 0.5.2       2024-04-23 [1]
#>  mlr3proba         * 0.6.1       2024-05-02 [1]
#>  mlr3tuning        * 0.20.0      2024-03-05 [1]
#>  mlr3viz             0.8.0       2024-03-05 [1]
#>  munsell             0.5.1       2024-04-01 [1]
#>  ooplah              0.2.0       2022-01-21 [1]
#>  palmerpenguins      0.1.1       2022-08-15 [1]
#>  paradox           * 0.11.1-9000 2023-11-22 [1]
#>  parallelly          1.37.1      2024-02-29 [1]
#>  param6              0.2.4       2023-11-22 [1]
#>  pillar              1.9.0       2023-03-22 [1]
#>  pkgconfig           2.0.3       2019-09-22 [2]
#>  R6                  2.5.1       2021-08-19 [1]
#>  Rcpp                1.0.12      2024-01-09 [1]
#>  reprex            * 2.0.1       2021-08-05 [1]
#>  RhpcBLASctl         0.23-42     2023-02-11 [1]
#>  rlang               1.1.3       2024-01-10 [1]
#>  rmarkdown           2.10        2021-08-06 [2]
#>  rpart               4.1-15      2019-04-12 [2]
#>  rstudioapi          0.15.0      2023-07-07 [1]
#>  scales              1.3.0       2023-11-28 [1]
#>  sessioninfo         1.1.1       2018-11-05 [2]
#>  set6                0.2.6       2023-11-22 [1]
#>  shape               1.4.6       2021-05-19 [2]
#>  stringi             1.7.3       2021-07-16 [2]
#>  stringr             1.5.0       2022-12-02 [1]
#>  survival            3.5-7       2023-08-14 [1]
#>  survivalmodels      0.1.191     2024-03-19 [1]
#>  tibble              3.2.1       2023-03-20 [1]
#>  tidyselect          1.2.0       2022-10-10 [1]
#>  utf8                1.2.4       2023-10-22 [1]
#>  uuid                1.2-0       2024-01-14 [1]
#>  vctrs               0.6.5       2023-12-01 [1]
#>  withr               3.0.0       2024-01-16 [1]
#>  xfun                0.25        2021-08-06 [2]
#>  yaml                2.2.1       2020-02-01 [2]
#>  source                                    
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  Github (xoopR/distr6@a7c01f7)             
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  Github (mlr-org/mlr3extralearners@6e2af9e)
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  https://mlr-org.r-universe.dev (R 4.1.1)  
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  https://mlr-org.r-universe.dev (R 4.1.1)  
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  Github (xoopR/param6@0fa3577)             
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  Github (xoopR/set6@a901255)               
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.2)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.1)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#>  CRAN (R 4.1.0)                            
#> 
#> [1] /Users/Lee/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library
#> [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library


The event probability at 12 months is data$prediction[[1]]$distr$survival(12) the cdf is 1 - surv, also known as risk or probability of dying up to time t

@John, thank you very much for your comment. I just wish to clarify the distinction between $cdf and $survival. The mlr3 book (mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter13/beyond_regression_and_classification.html#predict_type-distr) mentioned that $survival is for survival probability (prob of being alive). I also have worked example showing mlr3's prediction matching that of RMS and PEC. My understanding is that, in the absence of competing risk events, 1-surv is event probability. Risk is a trickier concept that may be considered as the exp(LP) or CRANK in the mlr3 language.

True about the interpretation of the "risk". If you restrict to right-censored survival predictions (so not risk-type predictions such as crank and lp - linear predictors) then in many R packages that implement these methods, practically in the code they use the word risk which is the event probability (as you said) but up to a time horizon (or the cumul distr fun of the time-to-event random variable). Also CIF => Cumulative Incidence Function I've seen a lot. An example well-written doc from aorsf => https://docs.ropensci.org/aorsf/reference/predict.ObliqueForest.html#arguments

@John, thank you for pointing out the nuances between cumulative hazard (cdf/risk) and event probs - they are indeed different entities.
